# python Tkinter hover эффект для label

Tags: python, tkinter

цикл создает несколько label-ов в качестве ссылок
нужно сделать hover эффект. приведенная функция не работает. текст изначально просто синий и на мышь не реагирует

```
def labelhover(w,ev):
    if ev is "enter":
        w["fg"]="red"
        #w.configure(foreground="red")
    elif ev is "leave":
        w["fg"]="blue"
        # w.configure(foreground="blue")


for u in urls:
    lbl = Label(frame1,
                text=u
                ,cursor="hand2"
                ,justify=LEFT
                ,wraplength=width-10
                )
    lbl.bind("<Enter>",labelhover(lbl,"enter"))
    lbl.bind("<Leave>",labelhover(lbl,"leave"))
    lbl.pack()
    lbl.bind("<Button-1>",lambda event,arg=j['adress']:openurl(event,arg))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `bind` ждёт ссылку на функцию, а не результат её вызова.

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_enter(event):
    event.widget.configure(fg="blue")

def on_leave(event):
    event.widget.configure(fg="black")


root = tk.Tk()

l1 = tk.Label(root, text="Первая метка")
l1.pack()

l1.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
l1.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

l2 = tk.Label(root, text="Вторая метка")
l2.pack()

l2.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
l2.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)

root.mainloop()
```